# problem with dependencies in my JHIPSTER application

Tags: angular, angular-material, jhipster, primeng

I generated a jhipster project but I have problems with the built-in dependencies (priemeng and angular material)jhipster 7.0.1, my package.json

```
"dependencies": {
    "-": "0.0.1",
    "@angular/animations": "^14.1.0",
    "@angular/common": "11.2.7",
    "@angular/compiler": "11.2.7",
    "@angular/core": "11.2.7",
    "@angular/forms": "11.2.7",
    "@angular/localize": "11.2.7",
    "@angular/material": "^14.2.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "11.2.7",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "11.2.7",
    "@angular/router": "11.2.7",
    "@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome": "0.8.2",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "1.2.35",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "5.15.3",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "9.1.0",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "13.0.0",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "6.0.0",
    "bootstrap": "4.6.0",
    "bootswatch": "4.6.0",
    "dayjs": "1.10.4",
    "ngx-infinite-scroll": "10.0.1",
    "ngx-webstorage": "7.0.1",
    "primeicons": "^6.0.1",
    "primeng": "^15.1.0",
    "rxjs": "6.6.7",
    "save": "^2.9.0",
    "swagger-ui-dist": "3.46.0",
    "tslib": "2.1.0",
    "zone.js": "0.11.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-builders/custom-webpack": "11.1.1",
    "@angular-builders/jest": "11.1.1",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin": "2.0.2",
    "@angular/cli": "11.2.6",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "11.2.7",
    "@angular/service-worker": "11.2.7",
    "@types/jest": "26.0.22",
    "@types/node": "14.14.37",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "4.20.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "4.20.0",
    "browser-sync": "^2.24.1",
    "browser-sync-webpack-plugin": "2.3.0",
    "concurrently": "6.0.0",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "6.4.1",
    "eslint": "7.23.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "8.1.0",
    "eslint-webpack-plugin": "2.5.3",
    "friendly-errors-webpack-plugin": "1.7.0",
    "generator-jhipster": "7.0.1",
    "husky": "4.3.8",
    "jest": "26.6.3",
    "jest-date-mock": "1.0.8",
    "jest-junit": "12.0.0",
    "jest-sonar-reporter": "2.0.0",
    "lint-staged": "10.5.4",
    "merge-jsons-webpack-plugin": "1.0.21",
    "prettier": "2.2.1",
    "prettier-plugin-java": "1.0.2",
    "prettier-plugin-packagejson": "2.2.10",
    "rimraf": "3.0.2",
    "simple-progress-webpack-plugin": "1.1.2",
    "typescript": "4.1.5",
    "wait-on": "5.3.0",
    "webpack": "4.46.0",
    "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "4.4.0",
    "webpack-merge": "5.7.3",
    "webpack-notifier": "1.13.0"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=14.16.0"
  },
  "cacheDirectories": [
    "node_modules"
  ],
  "jestSonar": {
    "reportPath": "target/test-results/jest",
    "reportFile": "TESTS-results-sonar.xml"
  }
}
```

I think it's problem related to the version of the integrated dependencies and I'm trying to have the compatibilities between these dependencies and the version of angular

What is wrong here? What else should I do?

Comment: Try `npm audit fix` command. it is basically to fix vulnerabilities but sometimes it updates the dependencies and it might solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your project has been generated with Angular 11 and you have added some libraries from Angular 14 (material, animations).

More, you have added PrimeNG 15 which requires Angular 15.

**This will never work**, either you must upgrade Angular or you should use older compatible versions of Material and PrimeNG.

I would also add that using both Material and PrimeNG in same project usually does not make sense as their purpose is overlapping and you will have hard time tuning styles to make your app look nice.

Comment: Thank you for your intervention in fact I have already updated the versions compared to version 11 of angular and it has passed